# Calculating 15mins data from Cumulative Sums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I came up with a problem.
I have real-time production data with **Machine Codes [M]** column, which has **DateTime** stamps [DateTime] with cumulative sums **[Cumulative]** column. From the original data, I created 15mins time intervals by flooring the DateTime column.

To problem is, I'd like to take latest CumulativeSum of the each machine for each **TimeBins**, and take the difference of each 15mins. time intervals. So, I will be able to calculate the 15mins. real-time production data of each machine with the new data frame, with a new column, named [Diff].

Please find the sample code for to represent my problem.

**Original Data:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'M':['18','18','18','19','19','19','18','18','18','19','19','19','19'],
             'Cumulative':['8','10','11','5','8','9','13','16','17','14','19','20','22'],
             'DateTime': ['2022-08-01 07:14:28','2022-08-01 07:25:58','2022-08-01 07:29:19',
                         '2022-08-01 07:13:17','2022-08-01 07:28:58','2022-08-01 07:29:01',
                         '2022-08-01 07:34:54','2022-08-01 07:36:02','2022-08-01 07:38:17',
                         '2022-08-01 07:33:46','2022-08-01 07:37:09','2022-08-01 07:38:17','2022-08-01 07:41:38']})
```

*I created 15mins. TimeBins by floor the DateTime to "15T" buckets.
And change the formats of the each column.*

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['TimeBins'] = df['DateTime'].dt.floor(freq='15T')
df['Cumulative'] = df['Cumulative'].astype('int32')
```

**The new dataframe that I'd like to have is as follows,**

```
pd.DataFrame({'M':['18','18','18',
                   '19','19','19'],
             'DateTime':['2022-08-01 07:14:28 ','2022-08-01 07:29:19','2022-08-01 07:38:17',
                        '2022-08-01 07:13:17','2022-08-01 07:29:01','2022-08-01 07:41:38'],
             'TimeBins':['2022-08-01 07:00:00','2022-08-01 07:15:00 ','2022-08-01 07:30:00',
                        '2022-08-01 07:00:00','2022-08-01 07:15:00','2022-08-01 07:30:00'],
             'Cumulative':['8','11','17',
                          '5','9','22'],
             'Diff':['NaN','3','6',
                    'NaN','4','11']})

    M   DateTime                TimeBins        Cumulative       Diff
0   18  2022-08-01 07:14:28 2022-08-01 07:00:00        8        NaN
1   18  2022-08-01 07:29:19 2022-08-01 07:15:00       11        3
2   18  2022-08-01 07:38:17 2022-08-01 07:30:00       17        6
3   19  2022-08-01 07:13:17 2022-08-01 07:00:00        5        NaN
4   19  2022-08-01 07:29:01 2022-08-01 07:15:00        9        4
5   19  2022-08-01 07:41:38 2022-08-01 07:30:00       22        11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['TimeBins'] = df['DateTime'].dt.floor(freq='15T')
df['Cumulative'] = df['Cumulative'].astype('int32')

cols = ['M','DateTime','TimeBins','Cumulative']
df = df.groupby(['M','TimeBins'], as_index=False).last()[cols]
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('M')['Cumulative'].diff()
print (df)
    M            DateTime            TimeBins  Cumulative  Diff
0  18 2022-08-01 07:14:28 2022-08-01 07:00:00           8   NaN
1  18 2022-08-01 07:29:19 2022-08-01 07:15:00          11   3.0
2  18 2022-08-01 07:38:17 2022-08-01 07:30:00          17   6.0
3  19 2022-08-01 07:13:17 2022-08-01 07:00:00           5   NaN
4  19 2022-08-01 07:29:01 2022-08-01 07:15:00           9   4.0
5  19 2022-08-01 07:41:38 2022-08-01 07:30:00          22  13.0
```

Another solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['Cumulative'] = df['Cumulative'].astype('int32')


cols = ['M','DateTime','TimeBins','Cumulative']

df = (df.groupby(['M',pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='DateTime')])[['DateTime','Cumulative']]
       .last().rename_axis(['M','TimeBins'])
       .reset_index()[cols])
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('M')['Cumulative'].diff()
print (df)
    M            DateTime            TimeBins  Cumulative  Diff
0  18 2022-08-01 07:14:28 2022-08-01 07:00:00           8   NaN
1  18 2022-08-01 07:29:19 2022-08-01 07:15:00          11   3.0
2  18 2022-08-01 07:38:17 2022-08-01 07:30:00          17   6.0
3  19 2022-08-01 07:13:17 2022-08-01 07:00:00           5   NaN
4  19 2022-08-01 07:29:01 2022-08-01 07:15:00           9   4.0
5  19 2022-08-01 07:41:38 2022-08-01 07:30:00          22  13.0
```

Comment: thanks, it almost works. I integrate your solution in to real-time data,
the code should be revised with "first" instead of "last".
df = df.groupby(['M','TimeBins'], as_index=False).first()[cols]